# Redux Toolkit RTK Query call endpoints in queryFn

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm using an endpoint with `queryFn` instead of `query` to perform many requests. Is there a way to calling endpoints that are already define instead of using `fetchWithBQ` ? 
Here is an example.

```
export const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "url",
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => {
    return {
      device: builder.query<Device, string>({
        query: (id) => `devices/${id}`, // repeat 1
      }),
      deployments: builder.query<Deployment[], string>({
        queryFn: async (arg, _api, _extraOptions, fetchWithBQ) => {
            // I would preferred to call the device endpoint directly.
            // It will prevent to repeat the url and get cached data.
          const result = await fetchWithBQ(`devices/${arg}`); // repeat 2
          return ...
        },
      }),
    };
  },
});
```

Answer (score 10):

No, at the moment that is not possible because it would add a tracking of "what depends on what else" to the whole things and that would get very complicated to manage internally.

You would usually do dependent queries just by using two `useQuery` hooks. And for abstraction of course you could combine those into a custom hook.

```js
const useMyCustomCombinedQuery = (arg) => {
  const result1 = useMyFirstQuery(arg)
  const result2 = useMySecondQuery(result1.isSuccess ? result1.data.something : skipToken)

  return {result1, result2}
}
```